# Wordpress. Get the data from admin-post.php after unsuccessful form validation

Tags: wordpress, forms, redirect, http-post, submit

I submit the form to admin-post.php:

```
 <form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php') ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="some-action">
    <input type="text" name="somename">
 </form>
```

And handle it in the backend:

```
 add_action( 'admin_post_some-action', function () {

    $isValid = // SOME VALIDATION HERE
    if($isValid){
        wp_redirect('next-step'); //redirect to the next form
        return;
    }

    wp_redirect('current-step'); //redirect back
});
```

If the form is not valid, I want to redirect back to the form with filled data and highlighted invalid inputs. The problem is that wp_redirect does not return any data at all. So user will need to fill all the data mannually again without even understanding wjat was wrong. I found 2 solutions:

1. **Use get param in the wp_redirect** - it may be good for just one input, but it will be awful, especially for the file and passwords inputs.
2. **Use $_SESSION** - it's a bit better, but still rough way to implement this.
3. **Use curl** - it's very dirty solution for the WP

I guess there should be some simple default way to handle this, as it's quite major thing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use transients if the user is logged in and set them to expire about 60 seconds, setting the data in your admin_post action then retrieving them in your form page.  I'm still looking for a nice solution that doesn't involve posting the form back to itself by setting `action=""` in the form and not using the `admin_post` action.

Answer (score -1):

Whether 'simple' or 'hard' programming, instructions need to be given to the machine. Think about how would you accomplish it with just plain PHP. You are basically being redirected to another page after unsuccessful login. Since HTTP is stateless, you can store the data either on the server side (in database, session, files..) or you pass the information in the URL. WordPress wouldn't just automatically start a session for you to store last form submission.